# disable jquery-chosen dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a select div that I'm using the [chosen jquery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to style and add features to (most notably, search).  The div looks something like this,

```
 <select data-placeholder="add a foobar" id="foobar" style="width: 350px;">
 <option value=""></option>
 </select>
```

And I'm using the chosen plugin like this,

```
 $('#foobar').chosen();
```

While some AJAX is loading, I'd like to disable the entire `<select>` div.  Maybe with something like this,

```
 $('#foobar').disable()
```

or this

```
 $('#foobar').prop('disabled', true)
```

I think you get the idea.

Any ideas on how to do this?  I've tried a number of different things, like using jquery idioms for disabling things, disabling the `<select>` which just disables the underlying select, not the chosen stuff on top of it.  I've even resorted to manually adding another div with a high `z-index` to just grey out the box, but I think that this is likely to be ugly and buggy.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You are disabling just your `select`, but chosen renders it as divs, and spans, etc. So after disabling your select you need to update the plugin to make the select widget disabled too. You can try this way:

```
$('#foobar').prop('disabled', true).trigger("liszt:updated");

//For non-older versions of chosen you would want to do:

$('#foobar').prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

I found the information [here](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/67)

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdFfA/218/)

Once you update the widget all it does is it unbinds the click or other events on the plugin and changes its opacity to 0.5. As there is no real disabled state for a div.

Comment: Looks like there is a typo in `liszt:updated`, shouldn't it be `list:updated?

Comment: `liszt` was correct, but now `chosen:updated` is the proper way to do it anyway.

Comment: Suggestion : You may need to specify the latest version of the code at first one in your answer since many of the users will be using the latest version. I used `liszt:updated` and didn't work since it isn't working in new versions.

Comment: `.trigger("chosen:updated");` It also serves to activate or deactivate, for example if you call it again in a function.

Comment: $('#foobar option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated"); will disable the other items in the dropbox except the selected item.

Answer (score 55):

In the lastest version of chosen, `liszt:updated` is not working anymore. You need to use `chosen:updated`:

```
$(".chosen-select").attr('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated")
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orlando/PrHDH/).

Answer (score 8):

PSL was correct, but chosen has been updated since.

Put this after you do the disabling:

```
$("#your-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#foobar').prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

This works Perfect!!!!
@chosen v1.3.0

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$("#foobar").prop('disabled',true).trigger("chosen:updated").chosen('destroy').chosen()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("chosen_one").chosen({
  max_selected_options: -1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#foobar").chosen().on('chosen:showing_dropdown',function() {
            $('.chosen-select').attr('disabled', true).trigger('chosen:updated');
            $('.chosen-select').attr('disabled', false).trigger('chosen:updated');
            $('.search-choice-close').hide();
    });
    $('.search-choice-close').hide();
});
```