# jquery-chosen disable does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm referring this issue to an answered thread: [disable jquery-chosen dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153417/disable-jquery-chosen-dropdown)

This actually did not work for me when I tried it. And neither did that Fiddle link demo worked for me (Firefox v22). What am I mssing here? I basically just need to disable the jquery-chosen UI element when the real original select element is disabled. Is there another way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that answer doesn't work with the last version.. they deprecated `liszt:updated` in favor of `chosen:updated`

something like this works

```
$(".chosen-select").prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated")
```

here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orlando/PrHDH/)

## Update

- Changing answer to use `prop` instead of `attr`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure you should use .prop() instead of .attr()
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @RobinNeal, i tested both, `attr` & `prop` worked for me

Comment: @Zeeshan It's more a matter of proper practices rather than what works. Please refer to the section about Prop vs Attr in the link I posted in my previous comment.